# When will the Graph API for Priority on a Planner task be available?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

Microsoft recently updated the Planner with a new Priority option on a Planner Task. We can't seem to find this in the Graph API. When can we expect that??

We have an Outlook Add-in for the online Planner. We want to update our add-in with the new priority field on the Task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently available on the /Beta version of the Graph API. V1.0 will be updated *probably* within the next month.

Comment: There is a field asigneePriotity, but isn't that just a hint for sorting..?

As far as I know you cannot get the prio of task via Graph API V1.0 but it is possible in the beta version.
@Ekelund : Did you manage to get the priority of a task via the V1.0 API? I am facing the same limitations...